# To do list app delete function js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an extremely basic to do list. I have researched and looked at many examples to no avail. All I want to do is have the ability to click an item that has been added to my list and have it deleted. I am not sure how to access the value of what Is entered in my items, or how to manipulate those into a function.

```js
function todoList() {
  let item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value //pulling value from input box
  let text = document.createTextNode(item) //turning input text into node
  let newItem = document.createElement('li') //creates a list
  newItem.appendChild(text) //appends task entered from input
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem) //appends the entered task to the list
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>To do list</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <form id="todoForm">
    <input type="text" id="todoInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="todoList"></ul>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you want to trap the "onclick" event for newItem.  In that event you'll have access to newItem (probably as a property of the event, since you're not using any libraries like jQuery).  Using that property, you can get enough information to perform a "removeChild".  But there is a LOT of research to get there ... my comment should point you in the right direction.  Google is your friend!

Comment: you can look into the `.addEventListener('click'` or `.onclick =` parts for example on how to add click event https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here is a likely course of actions. There are many ways you can do it, and here is one that is functional.

I have broken it down for you. I also renamed your add function to be a little more clear what it does:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
    <title>To do list</title>
    <!-- Put this in your style.css -->
    <style>
        .item {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form id="todoForm">
        <input type="text" id="todoInput">
        <button type="button" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoList"></ul>
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>

<script>
    function addItem(){
        //get current number of todo Items (for creating the ID)
        const currentNumberOfItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item').length
        console.log(currentNumberOfItems)
        console.log('Research:', document.querySelectorAll('.item'))

        const item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value //pulling value from input box
        const text = document.createTextNode(item) //turning input text into node
        const newItem = document.createElement('li') //creates a list
        newItem.id = currentNumberOfItems //give the new <li> an auto-incrementing id property
        newItem.classList.add('item') //add the item class so we can search for it by class
        //we didn't end up searching by class, but you can find every <li> on the page
        //using console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.item'))
        newItem.appendChild(text) //appends task entered from input
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem) //appends the entered task to the list

        const btn = document.createElement('button') // Create a <button> element
        const t = document.createTextNode('Delete')  // Create a text node
        btn.appendChild(t)                           // Append the text to <button>
        newItem.appendChild(btn)                     // Append <button> into the new <li>

        //we are going to create an event listener on the button
        //this takes 2 parameters
        //first = event type (on click)
        //second = callback function to run when the event is detected
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            console.log(event.target.parentNode) //we want the element in which the button exists
            console.log('Research:', event) //look at all the stuff in here!
            deleteItem(event.target.parentNode) //run our delete function
        })
    }

    //now that we have an event listener and know the parent
    //we just have to find a way to delete the parent
    //we can call the input anything, and it will be a DOM element (event.target.parentNode)
    function deleteItem(parent) {
        console.log(parent.id) //lets check the parent's id

        //we can use element.removeChild() to ditch the todo item
        //first, we have to get the <ul> somehow
        const todoList = document.getElementById('todoList') //let's get the <ul> by ID
        todoList.removeChild(parent) //cya later "parent that the button was inside of"
    }
</script>
```

I tried to make this a snippet, but it seems the code editor crashes when you delete, so I will leave it like this.

Bonus

You will see I used `const` instead of `let`, because it does not allow re-assignment, which tells JavaScript and other coders that you do not plan to change that variable once it is set.

You can sample that by putting this in your JS file:

app.js

```
'use strict'
const test = 'cool'
test = 'not cool'
console.log(test)
```

Notice the behaviour now with `let` (swap the code for this):

```
'use strict'
let test = 'cool'
test = 'not cool'
console.log(test)
```

This some basics with "immutability" that you should research a bit when you want to do some reading. It means you dont have to worry quite as much with strange bugs when you accidently mutate some variable. `const` will get mad if you try.

More advanced, you can still re-assign properties on objects when using `const`:

```
const object = {
    name: 'Bob Alice'
}
object.name = 'Not Bob Anymore'
```

When you use `let`, it tells yourself and other coders that you expect the value of the variable will likely change somewhere nearby in the code.

I recommend you try this out and if you ever encounter any issues, just Google it and you will quickly discover. Don't worry, nothing will blow up on you if you always use `const` "unless you cant". Issues will only occur in highly advanced code, with `const` vs. `let` vs. `var`.